# useDispatch() throwing error from reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm building an app that loads in Trump's tweets and visualizes them. Right now, I have the tweets in a .json file, but eventually I want to call an API asynchronously to fetch the tweets. However, my reducer keeps throwing a new error from the `default` clause in the `switch` statement, and I can't figure out why! The goal is to achieve `FETCH_TWEETS_SUCCESS`, which should be guaranteed since I'm just importing a .json file.

EDIT: The repo is here: https://github.com/inspectordanno/trump_tweets

I built out a `useEffect()` hook which will fetch data. Again, right now I'm just passing an .json file so the whole exercise is a bit overkill. Anyway, here is my app with the actions dispatched from the `useDispatch()` hook, a new hook from react-redux:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import tweets from '../../trump_r/tweets_cleaned.json';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

const TrumpApp = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {  
    let didCancel = false;

    const fetchData = () => {
      dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_TWEETS_INIT' });
      try {
        if (!didCancel) {
          dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_TWEETS_SUCCESS', payload: tweets });
        }
      } catch (error) {
        if (!didCancel) {
          dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_TWEETS_FAILURE' });
        } 
      }
    }
    fetchData();

    return () => {
      didCancel = true;
    };

  }, []);

  return (
      <h1>hello world</h1>
  );
}

export default TrumpApp;
```

This is my reducer:

```
const fetchTweetsReducerDefaultState = {
  isLoading: false,
  isError: false,
  data: 'data not loaded'
};

const fetchTweetsReducer = (state = fetchTweetsReducerDefaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_TWEETS_INIT':
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
        isError: false
      };
    case 'FETCH_TWEETS_SUCCESS':
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        isError: false,
        data: action.payload
      };
    case 'FETCH_TWEETS_FAILURE':
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: false,
        isError: true
      };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

export default fetchTweetsReducer;
```

Store is here:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import fetchTweetsReducer from '../reducers/fetchTweetsReducer';

export default () => {
  const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
      tweets: fetchTweetsReducer,
    }),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  );
  return store;
}
```

And finally for good measure, app.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import TrumpApp from './components/TrumpApp';
// import 'normalize.css/normalize.css';
// import './styles/styles.scss';

const store = configureStore();

const jsx = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <TrumpApp />
  </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(jsx, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I have the @next latest version of react-redux installed, and the latest version of everything. I even tried commenting out the `try/catch` block and just dispatching a `'FETCH_TWEETS_SUCCESS'` action, but I'm still getting the same error from my reducer. I'm assuming that there is some faulty logic in my reducer but I can't figure out what is going on.

Comment: what error do you mean? `throw new Error()` - this one? or some else?

Comment: yes. the error is thrown from throw new Error() from the default clause in the reducer.

Comment: I added the repo link above. Also, when I delete throw new Error() from the default clause and replace with return state, the whole app crashes.

Comment: oh, right, `redux` sends `@@redux/INIT` action first.

Comment: your `<TrumpApp />` tries to render itself. infinite recursion causes app to crash after a while.

Comment: oh woops! dumb mistake. I removed the self-rendering, but I'm still getting the error :(

Answer (score 1):

This is because Redux starts with `@@redux/INIT` action and your reducer on this action must return init state and not throw :-)

In your reducer on default just return your state like so:

```
default:
   return state;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working with modification suggested by @Oleksandr Nechai

Please find working example based on your code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/so56551086-mmsy5)

So it seems that errors are caused by something else